# Question about java.util.Calendar

Tags: java, date, calendar, java.util.date, java.util.calendar

I'm trying to understand the behavior with the following code.
My local time zone is UTC -7 (Arizona).

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,40);
cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);
System.out.println("1 UTC -4 Hour:" + cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
System.out.println("1 UTC -4 Day:" + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
System.out.println("1 UTC -7 Time Stamp:" + cal.getTime().toString());
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR,12);
System.out.println("2 UTC -4 Hour:" + cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
System.out.println("2 UTC -4 Day:" + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
System.out.println("2 UTC -7 Time Stamp:" + cal.getTime().toString());
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York")); //set time zone to UTC -4
System.out.println("3 UTC -4 Hour:" + cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
System.out.println("3 UTC -4 Day:" + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
System.out.println("3 UTC -7 Time Stamp:" + cal.getTime().toString());
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR,12);
System.out.println("4 UTC -4 Hour:" + cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
System.out.println("4 UTC -4 Day:" + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
System.out.println("4 UTC -7 Time Stamp:" + cal.getTime().toString());
```

It generates this output:

> 1 UTC -4 Hour:12
>   1 UTC -4 Day:27
>   1 UTC -7 Time Stamp:Tue Sep 27 12:40:37 MST 2011
>   2 UTC -4 Hour:0
>   2 UTC -4 Day:28
>   2 UTC -7 Time Stamp:Wed Sep 28 00:40:37 MST 2011
>   3 UTC -4 Hour:3
>   3 UTC -4 Day:28
>   3 UTC -7 Time Stamp:Wed Sep 28 00:40:37 MST 2011
>   4 UTC -4 Hour:12
>   4 UTC -4 Day:28
>   4 UTC -7 Time Stamp:Wed Sep 28 09:40:37 MST 2011

What I don't understand is why the first cal.set(Calendar.HOUR,12) causes the date to flip to the next day. It makes sense that using add() on one value would cause other values to be adjusted, but it doesn't make sense for set() to do that as well.

Is there some way to do an absolute set() where all other values are preserved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're setting "HOUR" rather than "HOUR_OF_DAY". It's therefore setting it to be "12 hours after the start of the afternoon" - i.e. midnight at the *end* of that day, so the start of the next. Think of it as saying, "I'm meant to be PM, so setting the hour is `midday + hours * 12`"

Personally I think that's still a bit odd behaviour, but I'd stick to using HOUR_OF_DAY instead... or preferrably, using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, I don't like that behavior. set(Calendar.HOUR, 12) should not behave different depending on what AM_PM is set to. I'll deal with this behavior in my existing project, but in the future I'll look into Joda Time.